# Integrating Crystal Reports RPT files in a Flutter Application

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, crystal-reports, blazor-webassembly

I'm exploring the possibility of using RPT files (Crystal Reports) in my Flutter application to generate reports. I've noticed that there's a precompiled library (SDK) for Crystal Reports available in C#. Since Flutter uses Dart, I'm wondering if there's a way to make use of this SDK in my Flutter project.

Here are a couple of approaches I've considered, but I'm not sure about the feasibility and potential challenges:

1. Converting the C# SDK to Dart: Is it possible to convert or rewrite the Crystal Reports SDK from C# to Dart so that it can be used in a Flutter project? If so, what are the steps involved, and are there any resources or tools that can simplify this process?
2. Using C# Snippets: Is it feasible to write a C# code snippet and integrate it into my Flutter application to work with Crystal Reports? If this is a viable option, what are the best practices for connecting the two languages and making them work seamlessly?
3. Blazor WebAssembly: I've heard about creating a Blazor project and compiling it to WebAssembly, which could potentially be used within a Flutter application. While this seems like a solution, I'm concerned about its complexity and any potential issues that may arise in the future. Has anyone attempted this approach, and what are the pros and cons?

I'm still in the research phase and haven't implemented anything yet, so I'd greatly appreciate any insights, guidance, or experiences you can share. If you have any alternative suggestions or resources that could help me achieve this integration, please feel free to share them.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!